# Cascading with CustomObjects

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I have these two objects:

```
public class BaseModule
{
    public long BaseModuleID { get; set; }

    public string ModuleName { get; set; }

    public bool CanOpen { get; set; }

    public bool CanConfigure { get; set; }
}

public class ActiveModule
{
    public long ActiveModuleID { get; set; }

    public long BaseModuleID { get; set; }

    public BaseModule Module { get; set; }
}
```

The BaseModule is in a 1:1 relation to the ActiveModule object and ActiveModule is a wrapper for BaseModule.

Now I want to save ActiveModule but it says that the column `BaseModuleID` has no default value for it. But in my object the child BaseModule.

I would know expect that the value of the child will be chosen to insert into the column.

Am I missing anything here or just dont really understand how cascading is done in Dapper?

Comment: If BaseModule will contains values of BaseModuleID then I think you don't need to declare BaseModuleID in ActiveModule. If you need to use that value then you will be able to use it by LINQ.

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need the foreign key attribute I think:

```
        public class ActiveModule
        {
            public long ActiveModuleID { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("Module")]
            public long BaseModuleID { get; set; }

            public BaseModule Module { get; set; }
        }

        public class BaseModule
        {
            public long BaseModuleID { get; set; }

            public bool CanConfigure { get; set; }
            public bool CanOpen { get; set; }
            public string ModuleName { get; set; }
        }
```